# Erro de charset no Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Segue linha do código em `php` com exemplo:

Se fizer assim, grava com aqueles caracteres estranhos:

```
INSERT INTO cliente (nome, endereco) VALUES ('ççoas sadoçççç','email');
```

Se fizer assim, grava normal:

```
INSERT INTO cliente (nome, endereco) VALUES (utf_utf8_decode('ççoas sadoçççç'),utf8_decode('email'));
```

Já mudei os `charsets` e `collation` da base, conexão e do `php` e nada.
Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Qual `IDE` você utiliza? Recentemente tive esse problema, a solução foi configurar a `IDE` para escrever no formato `UTF-8`.

Comment: Uso o eclipse e notepad++ e tb já setei o encoding e nada.

Comment: Encontrei o erro, fiz um "pente fino" e descobri que eu tinha colcado $conn->exec('SET CHARACTER SET **utf-8**'); e o correto é **utf8**. Obrigado a todos.